# Selenium Chromedriver threads decrease over time

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

My Python script for running multiple headed-mode Chromedriver sessions begins with a given thread count (4 in this example), where each thread represents an active browser session, and each thread loops through its unique allocation of an array of URL addresses from a CSV file. Browser instances open and close successfully, with the active number initially equal to the thread count. However, over time, the active count of Chromedriver sessions decreases to just 1, with the script continuing to run successfully on that 1 session. I'm hoping to learn whether the script can be modified so that both the thread-split arrays and thread count persist for the script's entire duration. Below are what seem to be the relevant excerpts controlling the threads and arrays:

```python
import multiprocessing
[...]
_threads = 4
[...]
    # Split the list into multiple arrays.
    arr = addresses
    ar = np.array_split(arr, _threads)
    # Create a list to store the processes.
    _processes = []
    # Loop through each array and create a new process to run the `workflow` function on it.
    for _ar in ar:
        _processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(
            target=workflow, args=(_ar,)))
[...]
    # Start each process.
    for p in _processes:
        p.start()

    # Wait for each process to finish before continuing.
    for p in _processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: You tagged this question with `multithreading` and you describe your code as using multithreading. But the very incomplete code you posted uses multiprocessing (it should probably be using multithreading since your Chromedriiver sessions are already running in separate processes). See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).